# SQL comparing column changes the last X hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing log entries that looks like this:

```
id | name     | level |  timestamp
5  | ironman  | 35    |  2019-01-06 11:37:40
6  | ironman  | 35    |  2019-01-06 11:38:40
7  | ironman  | 36    |  2019-01-06 11:39:40
8  | superman | 25    |  2019-01-06 11:39:49
```

I need help making a query that returns a list of levels gained the last X hours for each character, preferably sorted by amount gained.
So by this example my wanted result is this

```
id  |  name    |  gained  |  timestamp
7   | ironman  |  1       |  2019-01-06 11:37:40
8   | superman |  0       |  2019-01-06 11:37:40
```

Comment: check timestamp of superman! is it ok ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an aggregate query that compares the `MIN` and `MAX` level of each character :

```
SELECT 
    name,
    MAX(level) - MIN(level) as gained,
    MIN(timestamp)
FROM mytable
WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
GROUP BY 
    name
ORDER BY 
    gained desc
```

NB : this assumes that the `level` of a character may only increase. If the level of a character decreases, it will still appear as a gain.

Comment: This only appears to return 0 on gained? I doubled checked and I do have leveled up characters in my database.

Comment: @user3127399 : the query by default searches the last hour (`INTERVAL 1 HOUR`), you might need to change that

Comment: Yes I've tried changing it to 10 hours, but still the same result

Comment: Is the `level` field defined as numeric or as varchar ?

Comment: level is an int

Comment: @user3127399 : sorry I had a typo in the date condition... Fixed !

Answer (score 2):

You need to join the main table with a query that calculates the change in levels:

```
select levels.id, t.name, t.gained, t.timestamp
from (
select 
    name,
    max(level) - min(level) gained,
    max(timestamp) timestamp
from levels
where timestamp > now() - interval 10 hour
group by name
) t inner join levels
on 
  t.timestamp = levels.timestamp
  and
  t.name = levels.name
where levels.timestamp > now() - interval 10 hour
order by t.gained desc, t.name
```

I guess the timestamp in the expected output you posted about `superman` is wrong and it should be `2019-01-06 11:39:49`. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eDJTurYxzzNZszxJjraSCR/3)